# Make REST request in Windows 8 applications

Tags: c#, .net, rest, windows-8

I am trying to feth some data from Twitter .

I usually use the Hammock package  but it is not available on Windows 8 applications.

```
var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
            {
                Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
                SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
                ConsumerKey = AppSettings.consumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = AppSettings.consumerKeySecret,
                Token = this.accessToken,
                TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
                Version = "1.0"
            };



 var restClient = new RestClient
                {
                    Authority = "https://api.twitter.com",
                    HasElevatedPermissions = true,
                    Credentials = credentials

                };


                var restRequest = new RestRequest
                {
                    Credentials = credentials,
                    Path = "1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json",
                    Method = WebMethod.Post


                };



                restRequest.AddField("status", "Test");











                restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest,RequestCallBack);






        private void AutreRequestCallBack(RestRequest request, RestResponse response, object obj)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {


                   MessaBox.Show("Success");


                }




                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failure");


                }
            }
                );



        }
```

How can I use a similar method to  get (or post)   Twitter Data in a Windows 8 Application ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at [LinqToTwitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/). It's on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/linqtotwitter) and it will get you started quite quickly. It works on Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone.